# PrintWriter object doesn't print all the lines in text document to out put file

Tags: java, spring

```
 public String getText()
       {
           ApplicationContext appContext = new ClassPathXmlApplicationContext(new String[]{"spring-config-server.xml"});

Resource resource = appContext.getResource("file:D:\\text\\test.txt");
StringBuilder builder = new StringBuilder();
try{

  InputStream is = resource.getInputStream();
  BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(is));

  String line;
  PrintWriter out=null;
  while ((line = br.readLine()) != null) {
     //System.out.println(line);
       out = new PrintWriter(new FileWriter("D:\\outputfile.txt"));
      out.println(line);


      //br.close();
  } 

  out.close();
  br.close();

}catch(IOException e){
    e.printStackTrace();
    }
return builder.toString();

       }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `PrintWriter` is being assigned to a new instance during each loop iteration.  Declare the `PrintWriter` outside of the loop.

```
  String line;
  PrintWriter out= new PrintWriter(new FileWriter("D:\\outputfile.txt"));

  while ((line = br.readLine()) != null) {  
      out.println(line);
  }
```

Answer (score 1):

Create PrintWriter instance out of your while loop.

Answer (score 1):

You are creating new PrintWriters in the loop. Make it outside of it.

```
out = new PrintWriter(new FileWriter("D:\\outputfile.txt")); 
while ((line = br.readLine()) != null) {
 //System.out.println(line);

  out.println(line);


  //br.close();
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Move it outside the loop.Due to which `new` instance is created every line

```
out = new PrintWriter(new FileWriter("D:\\outputfile.txt"));
```